# How to query by date in react realm?

Tags: javascript, date, react-native, realm

I have a table called visitDetails, which I'm querying as follows,

```
realm
.objects("visitDetails")
.filtered("visitDate='"+new Date(response.date)+"' AND chemistId='"+response.chemist_id+"'");
```

I have saved the visitDate as date objects before, so I'm also querying by date objects.
I'm however, getting as error saying,

> Error: You must pass in a date argument to compare

But I'm already passing in a date argument...

> new Date( response.date )

, where response.date is in milliseconds.

Comment: Abhishek what can you tell me how did you save the date in the realm. The property is date type right? and in which format did you save?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now you are casting the `Date` object to a string by concatenate it with a string.
You should do something like this

```
realm.objects('visitDetails').filtered(
  "visitDate = $0 AND chemistId = $1",
  new Date(response.date),
  response.chemist_id
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick solution here. You should pass date as parameter.

```
.filtered("visitDate = $0 AND chemistId = $1", new Date(response.date), response.chemist_id);
```

Comment: voted for your answer but then found your expression not complete. please modify it to be a valid statement.

Comment: oh, I just did. :)

Comment: Voted for your answer, but found the explanation in the answer hyb175 gave more helpful..
Thank you for the help though :)